# Is Constructor Overriding Possible?

Tags: java, constructor, overriding

What I know is: the compiler writes a default no-argument constructor in the byte code. But if we write it ourselves, that constructor is called automatically. Is this phenomenon constructor overriding?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you describe isn't overriding. If you don't specify a default constructor, the
compiler will create a default constructor. If it's a subclass, it will call 
the default parent constructor([super()](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor-super.html)), it will also initialize all instance variables to
a default value determined by the type's default value(0 for numeric types, false for booleans, or null
for objects).

Overriding happens when a subclass has the same name, number/type of parameters, and
the same return type as an instance method of the superclass. In this case, the subclass
will *override* the superclass's method. [Information on overriding here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Comment: BTW it must not be the same return type: the overriding method must be return-type-substitutable for the overridden method (e.g. return type is a subtype)

Comment: "*If you don't specify a default constructor, the compiler will create a default constructor*"--No, if you don't define **any** constructor, the compiler will create one.

Answer (score 29):

Constructors are not normal methods and they cannot be "overridden". Saying that a constructor can be overridden would imply that a superclass constructor would be visible and could be called to create an instance of a subclass. This isn't true... a subclass doesn't have any constructors by default (except a no-arg constructor *if* the class it extends has one). It has to explicitly declare any other constructors, and those constructors belong to it and not to its superclass, even if they take the same parameters that the superclass constructors take.

The stuff you mention about default no arg constructors is just an aspect of how constructors work and has nothing to do with overriding.

Answer (score 18):

It is never possible. Constructor Overriding is never possible in Java.

This is because,

> Constructor looks like a method but
>   name should be as class name and no
>   return value.
>
> Overriding means what we have declared
>   in Super class, that exactly we have
>   to declare in Sub class it is called
>   Overriding. Super class name and Sub
>   class names are different.
>
> If you trying to write Super class
>   Constructor in Sub class, then Sub
>   class will treat that as a method not
>   constructor because name should
>   not match with Sub class name. And it
>   will give an compilation error that
>   methods does not have return value. So
>   we should declare as void, then only
>   it will compile.

---

Have a look at the following code :

```
Class One
        {
         ....
         One() { // Super Class constructor
          .... 
        }

        One(int a) { // Super Class Constructor Overloading
          .... 
        }
 }

Class Two extends One
                   {
                    One() {    // this is a method not constructor 
                    .....      // because name should not match with Class name
                   }

                    Two() { // sub class constructor
                   ....  
                   }

                   Two(int b) { // sub class constructor overloading
                   ....
                  }
 }
```

Comment: in the Two class, saying that One() is a method is incorrect, a method should always have a return type. just add it and I will agree with you .

Comment: Yes the constructor overriding is not possible if tried, Compiler gives left & right ;)(CE) return type required

Comment: It is unclear if the text in the quote block was taken from somewhere else (i.e. quoting) or only used as a highlight/emphasis.

Answer (score 5):

You can have many constructors as long as they take in different parameters.  But the compiler putting a default constructor in is not called "constructor overriding".

Comment: I cannot deny your answer, but by the fundamental rule of oop, in general every method must be overridable, provided its not declared final.

Answer (score 4):

Cannot override constructor. Constructor can be regarded as static, subclass cannot override its super constructor.

Of course, you could call protected-method in super class constructor, then overide it in subclass to change super class constructor. However, many persons suggest not to use the trick, in order to protect super class constructor behavior. For instance, FindBugs will warn you that a constructor calls a non-final method.

Answer (score 2):

Because a constructor cannot be inherited in Java and Method Overriding requires inheritance. Therefore, it's not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

> But if we write it ourselves, that
>   constructor is called automatically.

That's not correct. The no-args constructor is called *if you call it,* and regardless of whether or not you wrote it yourself. It is also called automatically if you don't code an explicit super(...) call in a derived class.

None of this constitutes constructor overriding. There is no such thing in Java.
There *is* constructor *overloading,* i.e. providing different argument sets.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor overriding is not possible because of following reason.

Constructor name must be the same name of class name. In Inheritance practice you need to create two classes with different names hence two constructors must have different names. So constructor overriding is not possible and that thought not even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not an override. Overrides technically occur in a subclass, but in this example the contructor method is replaced in the original class.

Comment: But as you can observe, that overriding is applicable to methods with same digital signature but different defination. So arent we really overriding the constructor?

Comment: No. The overriding concept only applies to inheritance. Are you looking for someone to tell you that your 'faculty' is wrong?