# Is using the Override annotation in constructors considered a good practice?

Tags: java, constructor, annotations

I've read that using the `@Override` annotation carries many benefits, and the consensus is that you should use it on every method that is being overridden.

Is it considered a good practice to use the `@Override` annotation in constructors too?

Comment: Show me an example where you `overwrite` a constructor.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099924/is-constructor-overriding-possible should help you.

Comment: Actually, using the `@Override` annotation on a constructor results in this error message: `annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

Constructors are not overridden.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Override` annotation makes no sense in the context of constructors. Maybe you are confusing [overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) with [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). This is an important difference. You don't override constructors but you may overload them.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding occurs when a subclass with same name, return type, number and type of parameters, is declared as an instance method of the superclass. In this case, the subclass will override the superclass's method.

If you don't specify a default constructor, the compiler will create a default constructor. This however is not Overriding.

When you extend a class, the Base class can either chain to the Baseclass constructor or create its own.

For eg:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base(int i) {}

    public Base(String str) {}
}

public class Derived extends Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        super(5);
    }
}

Derived d1 = new Derived(4); // Correct
Derived d1 = new Derived("4"); // Incorrect - constructor not implemented
```