# Override super class constructor with base class constructor using Reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, constructor

I have a scenario in which I want to Override a constructor creation of a base class with child class based on some condition from a class.

So following are the classes:
1) Ref
2) Other (Base class)
3) OtherImpl ( Child class of Other)
4) RefWorking (Main class)

Class Ref is calling constructor of Other class, I want to override this constructor with constructor of OtherImpl.

```
class Ref {

    private String s = "Original";
    private Other o;

    public Ref() {
    }

    public void method1(int a) {
        o = new Other();
        System.out.println("Method 1 : "+ s);
    }

    private void method2(String a) {
        System.out.println("Method 2 : "+ a);
    }
}

class Other {

    public Other() {
        System.out.println("Default Other Constructor");
    }
}


class OtherImpl extends Other {

    public OtherImpl() {
        System.out.println("Reflection Constructor");
    }
}

public class RefWorking {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Ref r = new Ref();

        Class c = r.getClass();

        OtherImpl oi = new OtherImpl();

        Field f = c.getDeclaredField("o");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(r, oi);

        r.method1(10);  
    }
}
```

It is giving following output:

Default Other Constructor
Reflection Constructor
Default Other Constructor
Method 1 : Original

But my expected output is :
Default Other Constructor
Reflection Constructor
Default Other Constructor
Reflection Constructor
Method 1 : Original

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cant override the `base class constructor`,for 
`OtherImpl class` cannot inherit the **constructor** of `Other Class` not to mention override it.

---

and this post may help you.
[Is Constructor Overriding Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099924/is-constructor-overriding-possible)