# Intellij Override Constructor Short Key

Tags: intellij-idea

If I want to override a method in a class then I press Ctrl + O short key that list all the methods that are available for overriding.
Do I have a similar short key to override Constructors?
Ctrl + O currently list only methods no information about constructors available.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case there is BaseClass and the SubClass that extends the base one, there is a quick-fix to "Create constructor matching super" in IntelliJ IDEA (it's available when you "Alt+Enter" on the `class SubClass extends BaseClass{}`). Please also see the discussion on constructor overriding in Java: [Is Constructor Overriding Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099924/is-constructor-overriding-possible)